# OBS won't detect hardware render and DaVinchi Resolve won't recognize OpenGL GPU

Tags: amd-graphics, opengl, amdgpu, obs-studio, davinci-resolve

I have an AMD RX 580 GPU and OBS won't detect hardware render AND DaVinchi Resolve won't recognize OpenGL GPU. I use the mesa drivers. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you stick to the LTS versions of Ubuntu you would be able to install and use the AMDGPU-PRO driver by AMD.

I do not use DaVinci Resolve myself, but read elsewhere that with the PRO driver it should work.

For my gaming rig on the other hand I do not rely on the PRO driver, but go with Hirsute, the Xanmod kernel and kisak's Mesa PPA which gives me a pretty decent performance. I wrote a guide on how to set this up here:
https://zyanklee.de/2021/06/01/amd-rx6xxx-ubuntu-groovy/
I did not yet update the article, but it works with Hirsute just the same.